# Why do values of an array count down multiple times with this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When you use this code

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var y = []


x.forEach(elt => {
    for(let i = 0; i < elt; i++){
        y.unshift(i)
    }
})

console.log(y)
```

it keeps counting down the array 'x' the length of x times.
Please explain this to me.

Comment: You have two loops: `forEach`, and `for` nested within it. For each element `elt` of `x`, you repeat the inner body `elt` times.

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: Which part do you not get? I do not know how to simplify this further; so help us help you. If you try to execute that code in your head, what _specifically_ is confusing? It may be a bit more obvious what is happening if you replace `unshift` with `push`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it know, I guess I didn't read your answer correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is doing exactly what you're asking it to do.

You are running a for-loop for every element in `x`.

So you are running

```
for (let i = 0; i < x[0]; i++) ... //i goes from 0 to 0
for (let i = 0; i < x[1]; i++) ... //i goes from 0 to 1
for (let i = 0; i < x[2]; i++) ... //i goes from 0 to 2
for (let i = 0; i < x[3]; i++) ... //i goes from 0 to 3
...
```

That's why you're getting those 9...0, 8...0, 7...0, and so on.

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let y = []


x.forEach(elt => {
    console.log(`For the element ${elt}`);
    //For each element in x, you are executing the following loop:
    for(let i = 0; i < elt; i++){
        console.log(`unshifting ${i}...`);
        y.unshift(i)
    }
    console.log(`End of each element (${elt}): ${y}`);
})

//if you want each element in x to unshift into y, you need to simply:

const z = [];

x.forEach(elem => z.unshift(elem))
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way to achieve the same result:

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const y = []

x.forEach(n => x.slice(0, n).forEach((_, i) => y.unshift(i)))
```

Code with explanation:

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const y = []

// For each number in x array:
x.forEach(n => 
  // Create a new array from 0 to the current n number:
  // [0, ..., n]
  x.slice(0, n).forEach((_, i) => 
    // And iterate adding the current i index to the beginning of y array
    y.unshift(i)
  )
)

console.log(y)
```